# Is this possible ? SQL Operators < && !=

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry im just new to mysql and php world. can someone help me?

There is an error of

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND NOT= End_date LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

This is the sql code

```
SELECT * FROM config_modi_ord WHERE Start_date < && != End_date
```

Comment: Did you want the `<=` _less than and not equal to_ operator? You can also write it as `s < e AND s != e`

Comment: *"Is this possible ? SQL Operators < && !="* - `There is an error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND NOT= End_date LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"` - obviously not. What are you trying to do here? `WHERE Start_date < End_date && XXX != YYY` ? hard to say what you want to query for. You need to elaborate.

Comment: just do "Start_date <  End_date"

Comment: `< && !=`? that would be a weird row having a start date thats greater than its end date

Comment: ow im sorry. i mean im trying to get the late action of the user. SELECT * FROM config_modi_ord WHERE date_acknowledge > End_date but when i run that i also get the row that have the same date. like End date is May 5 and date acknowledge is may 5. i want to get only the row that is Greater than end date –

Comment: you basically answered your own question. however, you need to give us more information.

Comment: instead of `!=` you would use `IS NOT`, so `Start_date IS NOT  End_date`

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  If you believe you are getting incorrect results, please edit the question to show an example of *exactly* the wrong result you are getting, and *exactly* why you believe it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `datetime` or just `date` fields? If you're comparing `datetime` fields that fall on the same day, but different times, then you will get some that appear to fall on the same day.  If you just want to compare the date component only, you can extract it using the `date()` function, so try this:

`select * from config_modi_org where date(date_acknowledge) > date(end_date)`

If that still isn't what you want, then you really need to add your table schema, some sample data and your exact query to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column you are planning to use, in all filter conditions.

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM config_modi_ord WHERE Start_date < End_date
```

Comment: the "and not equal to" is suprfluous if the first condition is met, ie start_date being less than end_date, it cannot equal end_date

Comment: ow im sorry. i mean im trying to get the late action of the user.
SELECT * FROM config_modi_ord WHERE date_acknowledge >  End_date

but when i run that i also get the row that have the same date. like 
End date is May 5  and date acknowledge is may 5.

i want to get only the row that is Greater than end date

Comment: See @pala_'s answer above